# Variable not passing to other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table.  When users click a table cell jquery grabs the id attribute and the name attribute of the child (input tags) that are inside of the cell.  When I alert the individual variables they alert correctly.  However when I return the values to an array and alert them else where in the script I run in to issues. For example when I alert the values in another function I get [object HTMLTableCellElement].

I have declared the id and name variables outside of any function at the top of my script after the document.ready.  Why can't get the proper values of the id and name in to another anonymous functions or functions.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var id = 0;
        var name = 0;
        var values2 = [];

        //when a table cell is clicked
        values2 = $('table tr td').click(function() { 

            //grab the id attribute of the table cell's child input tags that have a class of hidden
            id = $(this).children("input[class='hidden']").attr("id");
            alert( id ); //<----- alerts id properly (output for example is 25)

            //grab the name attribute of the table cell's child input tags that have a class of hidden
            name = $(this).children("input[class='hidden']").attr("name");
            alert( name ); //<----- alerts id properly (output for example is firstinput)

            return [id , name]; //<------ here is where I try to return both these values in to an array
                                // so that I can use the values else where in the script.  However 
                                // I am not able to use the values
        });

        $( "#nameForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
            // Stop form from submitting normally
            event.preventDefault();
            alert(values2[0]);  // <----alerts [objectHTMLtableCellElement]
                                //this should alert ID

            var posting = $.post( "comments.php", $('#nameForm').serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            });

            return false;
            // $('#result').html(term);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please indent correctly before submitting your question.

Comment: also, jsfiddles are preferable when it comes to code blocks this big

Comment: Your return does nothing.  It's not within a function (technically, it's in the Document ready function, but that's not a "function" in the sense that you are trying to use the return).  Additionally, you're setting your `values` variable to be equal to a function, not to the returned value of the function.

Comment: Where are you trying to use them elsewhere in the script? The click handler doesn't accept an array as a return value only a boolean.

Comment: You are setting the item equal to the element, not the return of it's click function. Have you tried setting the click function and then doing `values2 = $('table tr td').click();`? Although I have doubts that this would actually work.

Comment: `return [id,name]` returns to the click event part and not to `values2`

Comment: my return is inside of an anonymous function which is listening for a click of a table cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
values2 = $('table tr td').click(function(){ 
    return [id , name];
});
```

Use

```
$('table tr td').click(function(){ 
    values2 = [id , name];
});
```

Comment: changing return to the actual variable to which the values would be stored in seemed to work.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
values2 = $('table tr td').click(function() {
```

When you pass a function to `click` you are saying "When this is clicked, call this function".

The calling function then continues.

The return value of `click()` is not the result of running the function you pass to click.

If you want to use the values in response to the click, then you need to do so *inside the function you pass to click* (or a function it calls).

If you want to store them as a global for use later, then you need to assign them to the global *inside the function you pass to click* and not as a return value.